# PHP: Calculating Monthly/Yearly Billing Dates - Same day next month

Tags: datetime

I've been looking for a way to accurately calculate the next/future billing date in a way that a month will not be skipped. For example for Jun 31 I want the next billing date to be Feb 28 (or 29 when applicable).
I found this [great solution](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/php-calculating-monthly).
Here is an update of that code to support more than 1 month in the future.
Hope that helps.

Code:

```
function calculateBillingDate($startDate, $numberOfCycles = 1) {

    $currentMonth = date('n', $startDate);
    $nextMonth = (($currentMonth + $numberOfCycles) % 12);
    if ($nextMonth === 0) {
        $nextMonth = 12;
    }

    $targetDate = new \DateTime();
    $targetDate->setTimestamp($startDate);

    $targetDate->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $numberOfCycles . 'M'));
    while ((int)$targetDate->format('m') !== $nextMonth) {
        $targetDate->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    }

    return $targetDate;

}
```

Comment: LOL ???????????????????????????????????

Comment: May I ask what is so funny?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this one should be in https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/topics instead.

Comment: @felipsmartins so, should I re-post this on https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/topics ? I just want to share this solution.

Comment: This was really useful, thanks @YarivAzatchi!